# How to show textview for couple of seconds in playing video android tv leanback?

Tags: android, kotlin, leanback

I need to show textview inside of the video that playing for 5 seconds and hide it in android tv. Here you can I used the code to show video, its from android tv leanback. But I can't put a text for couple of seconds. Could you help?

```
class PlaybackVideoFragment : VideoSupportFragment() {

    private lateinit var mTransportControlGlue: PlaybackTransportControlGlue<MediaPlayerAdapter>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val (_, title, description, _, _, videoUrl) =
            requireActivity().intent?.getSerializableExtra(DetailsActivity.ARG_SPORT) as Sport

        val glueHost = VideoSupportFragmentGlueHost(this@PlaybackVideoFragment)
        val playerAdapter = MediaPlayerAdapter(requireContext())
        playerAdapter.setRepeatAction(PlaybackControlsRow.RepeatAction.INDEX_ONE)

        mTransportControlGlue = PlaybackTransportControlGlue(requireContext(), playerAdapter)
        mTransportControlGlue.host = glueHost
        playerAdapter.setDataSource(Uri.parse(videoUrl))
        mTransportControlGlue.playWhenPrepared()

    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mTransportControlGlue.pause()
    }

}
```